# jQuery .hide() and .show() don't work until page is clicked

Tags: jquery

OK, this is weird. On my page, whenever I call .hide() or .show() on an element, nothing happens until I click somewhere (anywhere) else on the page. The behaviour wasn't occurring earlier and I'm not sure what I did that led to it creeping in.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and bootstrap as my css framework (with a lot of modification). The behaviour occurs with Chrome, Firefox and Safari (on OSX). I've pared back the javascript to nothing but jQuery and my .hide() call and it still occurs. There is no error message displayed in the console.

I don't even know how to go about debugging this problem. I find it absolutely bizarre and googling hasn't revealed anything. Is there anything I can do with Developer Tools or similar to find out why .hide() isn't working as expected?

I'm using coffeescript. Here is the coffeescript;

```
$('#recipient_type').blur ->
  if $(this).val() == 'Other'
    $('#recipient-details').show()
  else
    $('#recipient-details').hide()
```

This is the javascript that it compiles to;

```
$('#recipient_type').blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === 'Other') {
        return $('#recipient-details').show();
      } else {
        return $('#recipient-details').hide();
      }
    });
```

but the phenomenon doesn't only occur with my code. For example, the bootstrap-alert.js alert dismissal script gives me the same problem.

Comment: is your show/hide code running in response to some user action on page like changing a value of a textbox

Comment: So after you click out of the object you have to click a second time for the hide/show to work?

Comment: Alright, I'm doing a huge facepalm on the blur example. But the reason I became confused is the same behaviour when I close one of the bootstrap alerts on the page. It fades out but then the blank space doesn't disappear until the page is clicked elsewhere. Separate problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint on the code that executes the hide to see if it is even executing.

It's a blur so, by definition it will not exceute until you move off of the active object.